# How to import submodule of other project

Tags: go, dependency-management, vgo

I am trying to import the following git project `github.com/tebeka/selenium`

When I use standard Go dependency management, it is as simple as `go get github.com/tebeka/selenium`, and then

```
import ("github.com/tebeka/selenium"
        "github.com/tebeka/selenium/chrome")
```

However, when I try to do the same thing with vgo (modules), I'm getting the following error:

```
unknown import path "github.com/tebeka/selenium/chrome": cannot find module providing package github.com/tebeka/selenium/chrome
```

Go mod generates following go.mod file

```
module mymodule

require (
    github.com/BurntSushi/toml v0.3.1
    github.com/op/go-logging v0.0.0-20160315200505-970db520ece7
    github.com/tebeka/selenium v0.9.3
)
```

Comment: You are requiring v0.9.3, which doesn’t have a chrome package.

Comment: @JimB Thank you so much! Simple `go get github.com/tebeka/selenium@master` solved my issue